# How fetch data from firebase realtime database in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from Firebase in React.
My data is structured like this:

[image]

My code currently looks like this:

```
fire.database().ref(outputClassName).once("value", snapshot => {
      let classStudents = [];
      snapshot.forEach(snapsh => {
        //classStudents.push(snapsh.val());
        let student = "";
        student = snapsh.val();
        alert(student);
        fire.database().ref(outputClassName).child(student).once("value", snapsho => {
          let studentSubjects = [];
          snapsho.forEach(snaps => {
            //studentSubjects.push(snaps.val());

            fire.database().ref(outputClassName).child(student).child(snaps.val()).once("value", snapsh => {
              let subjectNotes = [];
              snapsh.forEach(snap => {

                subjectNotes.push(snap.val());

              });

              studentSubjects.push(subjectNotes);

            });
          });

          classStudents.push(studentSubjects);

        });

      });
      setRenderData(classStudents);
    });
```

I am getting an error for this code. Can someone help me with a working solution ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text instead of image. Also, do you need realtime listeners in this usecase or do you want to fetch data only once when `outputData()` is ran?

Comment: I want to fetch data only when function outputData() is ran.

Comment: Okay you shouldn't be using `.on()` because that'll fetch data whenever it's changed in database. Use `.once()` instead.

Comment: I tried with ".once()", but I still get same error for this line of code ```fire.firebase().ref(outputClassName).child(student).on("value", snapshot => {```      the error says:                                
```firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.firebase is not a function```

Comment: Have you tried my answer? and you have not mentioned any error in your question. Can you add a screenshot of the error as well ?

Comment: Look at last comment. I edited it.

Comment: Oh okay, I was about to point that when I first saw it...  can you replace `fire.firebase()` with `firebase.database()` ? Also share the code where you have initialized Firebase if you still get the issue.

Comment: I replace it. Now I get the error ```child failed: path argument was an invalid path = "[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"``` for the same line of code.

Comment: I don't understand why because the child in this case is the name of the student and it is not empty and not contain ".","#", "$", "[" or "]".

Comment: Please update your question with your latest code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.once()` instead of `.on()` when data has to fetched only once. Also when you fetch data at path `/10 A`, it will fetch the complete node so you don't have to request data of every student in that class again.

```js
function outputData() {
    fire.database().ref(outputClassName).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
      const classData = snapshot.val()
      const students = Object.keys(classData)

      students.forEach((student, i) => {
        const subjects = Object.keys(classData[student])
        console.log(`${i+1} Name: ${student}`)
        console.log(`Subjects: ${JSON.stringify(subjects)}`)
        console.log("===")

        // render the data to HTML as per needs
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: For your solution I get the next error: ```Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): snapshot.data is not a function```

Comment: @Elisei_01 my bad. it should be `snapshot.val()`

Comment: It works, but it doesn't get the note. It get only class, name and subject.

Comment: Where are notes stored @Elisei_01 ?

Comment: You can see that in the screenshot class: 10 A, student: Daria Popa, subject: Chim, note: 8